# Explanation of swap procedure in Ada

Tags: ada

I want to know how this swap procedure work in Ada 95, here is the code:

```
Procedure swap (x,y : in out float) is
    t:float;
begin
    t:=x; x:=y; y:=t;
end;
```

Please explain each step, especially `swap (x,y : in out float)` and what `in out` stands for.

Thanks.

Comment: This is the kind of thing you should learn as you study the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x` and `y` are two `float` variables which are both passed *in* to the function and passed *out* (back) to the caller.

It's a way of specifying a *type* of call by reference (something I hope C will eventually have so as to avoid pointer complexity), so that changes to `x` and `y` within the procedure are echoed back to the caller. The alternative is, of course, pass by value where the variables within the function are local copies, and do not affect the *actual* variables in the caller.

I say a *type* of call by reference since that's not exactly the case. True call by reference would have the passed parameters changing as soon as the parameters are changed within the procedure

In Ada, changes to the variables within the procedure are not immediately reflected back to the caller. Instead, they're copied back on successful procedure exit. By way of example, an exception will not involve changes to the parameters that were passed in, even if they've already been modified within the procedure when the exception occurs.

Beyond that, it's a simple three-way transfer to swap the values. The steps are:

```
start    =>   x = 7, y = 9

t := x   =>   x = 7, y = 9, t = 7
x := y   =>   x = 9, y = 9, t = 7
y := t   =>   x = 9, y = 7, t = 7

finish   =>   x = 9, y = 7
```

Comment: This information is not quite correct.  The parameters are passed by copy-in and copy-back, not by reference.  This means that local copies of the variables are made, and changes to the variables do not affect the variables in the call, **until** the procedure is completed, and **then** the outside variables are changed.  If an exception is raised, the outside variables are never changed even if the procedure modified the parameters.  This is the case for scalar parameters like `float` or `integer`; some others are passed by reference and some are implementation-dependent.

Comment: @ajb, have updated answer based on your comments. Feel free to check and offer any further advice if you think it can be improved further. Thanks.